# How can I extract the required data from a page with JSON it's source?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

For example, here is a QR Image:

[image]

[Source](http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HelloWorld)

[This API](http://api.qrserver.com/v1/read-qr-code/?fileurl=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.qrserver.com%2Fv1%2Fcreate-qr-code%2F%3Fdata%3DHelloWorld) decodes the QR and outputs it's content which is "HelloWorld" in this case.

How can I use `file_get_contents()` or a similar function to fetch the required data.

Comment: You can `file_get_contents()` the api URI and then access the data after `json_decode()`ing it. So what is the problem?

Comment: `file_get_contents()` won't work. I have nothing to pass to `json_decode()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually is is possible to use `file_get_contents()` to access it. (<sup>*tested AND working*</sup>)

```
<?php 

$url = 'http://api.qrserver.com/v1/read-qr-code/?fileurl=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.qrserver.com%2Fv1%2Fcreate-qr-code%2F%3Fdata%3DHelloWorld';

$stuff = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($stuff);

print_r($data);

?>
```

Which returns this object:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => qrcode
            [symbol] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [seq] => 0
                            [data] => HelloWorld
                            [error] => 
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Allowing you to loop through (using `foreach()`) to echo out the stuff as you require.

```
foreach($data as $item) {
    echo $item->symbol[0]->data;
}
```

Or simply:

```
echo $data[0]->sybmol[0]->data;
```

And that will give you the desired: `HelloWorld`

Comment: Thanks alot for helping me with JSON. Yes, it works.

Comment: @user3296203 Perfectly alright mate :)