# QR code information extract

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, qr-code

I'm currently experimenting with trying to extract the information from a QR code located on a local web server. There's an example below (Example 1), however, in that case, the file is online and on the same domain.

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923658/how-can-i-extract-the-required-data-from-a-page-with-json-its-source)

My code consists of a user selecting a png QR code from their computer and pressing a submit button. The form should use Ajax and JSON to upload the file through the provided API and receive the information in an array.

Here's the code I have available:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>QR Code Reader</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript">
function fileUpload(){
 //grab form data
 var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
 console.log(formData);
 
  $.ajax({
   url: 'http://api.qrserver.com/v1/read-qr-code/',
   method: 'POST',
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   data: formData,
   //async: true,
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   //crossDomain: true,
   processData: false,
   success: function returnedResult(result){
    console.log(result);
   },
   error: alert('error')
  });
 
 
 return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://api.qrserver.com/v1/read-qr-code/" method="POST">
 <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE (maximum file size in bytes) must precede the file input field used to upload the QR code image -->
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1048576" />
    <div class="form-group">
     <!-- The "name" of the input field has to be "file" as it is the name of the POST parameter -->
  <label for="file">Choose QR code image to read/scan:</label>
  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" placeholder="Enter email" name="file">
    </div>
    <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick="fileUpload(this.form,'http://api.qrserver.com/v1/read-qr-code/','upload'); return false;">Submit</button> -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick="fileUpload(); return false;">Submit</button>
</form>
  
  
<div id="upload"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a sample image:
[HelloWorld](http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HelloWorld)

Running this code results in a Console error (in Chrome). Any help is appreciated.

Best regards.

Comment: Can you please describe the problem and post the error that you see in the console? What exactly is your question here?

Comment: check this [example](http://demo.phpgang.com/decode-qr-code/) for decoding qrcode

Comment: @Bugfixer thank you! that worked